# Filter table rows based on select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, jquery-selectors

I need to filter table rows based on select value. When selected value is "" (empty) table must be hidden. If select value is lets say 1, table must be visible and it must show only rows where first table column hold value 1.

The problem is that this id column hold multiple ids like 1,2.
Since my JQuery skill are not the best i need you guys to help me complete my code

My selector

```
<select id='mySelector'>
   <option value="">Please Select</option>
   <option value='1'>A</option>
   <option value='2'>B</option>
   <option value='3'>C</option>
</select>
```

My table

```
<table id='myTable'>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>ids</th>
         <th>name</th>
         <th>address</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1,2</td>
         <td>Jhon</td>
         <td>Doe</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>Mike</td>
         <td>Poet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>2,3</td>
         <td>Ace</td>
         <td>Ventura</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

My script

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('table').hide();
    $('#mySelector').change( function(){
      $('table').show();
      var selection = $(this).val();
      var dataset = $('#myTable').find('tr');
          $.each(dataset, function(index, item) {
            //help
          });
    });
});
```

And here is working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HLDoxNQmmXMvaJ0XPLit)

If you need any additional information, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have control of the markup?  Could you change the table markup, for example? This would be FAR simpler if you could add some attributes to the markup: `<tr data-id="[2,3]">` for example.

Comment: yes i have control of markups

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *filter* the row based on the content of the `td` that contains the *id*s:

1. Your *dataset* must be `$('#myTable tbody').find('tr')` so that it does not show / hide the `thead`
2. First show all the table `tr`s using `dataset.show()`
3. Now filter the `tr`s that you don't need to be shown using this:

   ```
   dataset.filter(function(index, item) {
     return $(item).find('td:first-child').text().split(',').indexOf(selection) === -1;
   }).hide();
   ```

See demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('table').hide();
  $('#mySelector').change(function() {
    $('table').show();
    var selection = $(this).val();
    var dataset = $('#myTable tbody').find('tr');
    // show all rows first
    dataset.show();
    // filter the rows that should be hidden
    dataset.filter(function(index, item) {
      return $(item).find('td:first-child').text().split(',').indexOf(selection) === -1;
    }).hide();

  });
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.styled-select.slate {
  height: 34px;
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<select id='mySelector' class="styled-select slate">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value='1'>A</option>
  <option value='2'>B</option>
  <option value='3'>C</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table id='myTable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ids</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1,2</td>
      <td>Jhon</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Mike</td>
      <td>Poet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2,3</td>
      <td>Ace</td>
      <td>Ventura</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i love the explanation trough code and solution! Thx

Comment: Notice: minified version of jQuery should be used.

Comment: @kukkuz- I have tried your code.But its not working.I am having textbox filter as row header for each column and used keyup function to show the rows matching the text entered in filter textbox. How can we use your code to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Short solution using `:contains()` selector:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('table').hide();

    $('#mySelector').change( function(){
      var selection = $(this).val();
      $('table')[selection? 'show' : 'hide']();

      if (selection) {  // iterate only if `selection` is not empty
        $.each($('#myTable tbody tr'), function(index, item) {
          $(item)[$(item).is(':contains('+ selection  +')')? 'show' : 'hide']();
        });
      }

    });
});
```

Test link: https://plnkr.co/edit/zNQNFVBIPSyPjEyU7I1J?p=preview

---

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code

```
$("#mySelector").on("change",
           function(){
               var a = $(this).find("option:selected").html();

               $("table tr td:first-child").each(
                   function(){
                       if($(this).html() != a){
                           $(this).parent().hide();
                       }
                       else{
                           $(this).parent().show();
                       }
                   });
           });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which you can test [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m3jjzd0v/3/)

```
$(function() {
    $('table').hide();
    $('#mySelector').change( function(){
      $('table').show();
      var selection = $(this).val();
      var dataset = $('#myTable').find('tr');

      dataset.each(function(index) {
        item = $(this);
        item.hide();

        var firstTd = item.find('td:first-child');
        var text = firstTd.text();
        var ids = text.split(',');

        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
        {
            if (ids[i] == selection)
          {
            item.show();
          }
        }
      });
    });
});
```